# Sender email converts from sender@domain.tld to b.16.16.229f5073c3f9ee97@domain.tld

Tags: civimail, mailing, drupal-9, mailserver

related to this one ["DB Error: no database selected" error if Outbound Mail SMTP username contains @](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45260/db-error-no-database-selected-error-if-outbound-mail-smtp-username-contains)

Happens while testing mailings on a simple fresh CiviCRM setup - there are no extra Drupal modules or Civi extensions installed.

"From" email address looks fine at message creation: "Name" email@domain.tld Tested with CIVICRM_MAIL_SMARTY in civicrm.settings.php in both options.  "Track replies using VERP in Reply-To header" and  "Enable CiviMail to generate Message-ID header" are disabled.

Perhaps part of a bigger malformed mailings issue, where HTML content arrives as a plain text.  Haven't seen this before, looks like some content "filtering" being applied but not sure by whom.

Since Ckeditor5 does not have "Source" button any longer it is hard to tell if template code has been changed immediately, but after switching Ckeditor5 off and looking to the template source I've found the HTML markup wrapper

```
<html><head></head><body>  ... </body></html>
```

has been stripped off  and the remaining part is wrapped in `<figure>` - which is different from default mailing templates markup on civicrm drupal 8 demo.

[image: This is how it looks]

*Drupal 9.5.10, PHP 8,2, CiviCRM 5.63.1*

Comment: The answer is here https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45260/db-error-no-database-selected-error-if-outbound-mail-smtp-username-contains - same for this issue and the one on the link.