# "DB Error: no database selected" error if Outbound Mail SMTP username contains @

Tags: civimail, mailing, smtp, drupal-9

cross-related: **[Sender email converts from sender@domain.tld to b.16.16.229f5073c3f9ee97@domain.tld](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45259/sender-email-converts-from-senderdomain-tld-to-b-16-16-229f5073c3f9ee97domain)**

The title says it all: saving Outbound Mail settings with SMTP username containing "@",
extended log message says

```
      SELECT * FROM  civicrm_setting 
      WHERE (  civicrm_setting.name  = mailing_backend )  
      AND (  civicrm_setting.domain_id = 1 ) 
      AND (  civicrm_setting.is_domain = 1 )  
      [nativecode=2027 ** Malformed packet]
```

*Drupal 9.5.10, PHP 8,2, CiviCRM 5.63.1*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple: despite of Cpanel new email account "Welcome" email states SMTP port to use is 465, it is actually **587**.

*No sense in asking why CiviCRM throws MySQL/DB connection error instead of "wrong SMTP credentials" notification, nor why wrong SMTP port information arrives from Cpanel.*